# Touch monitors for Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, monitor, touchscreen

I'm looking for a touchscreen monitor that is at least 19 inches diagonally and is fairly cheap (hopefully a similar price to the Windows 7 touch monitors made by HP, Dell, Planar, etc., which are $200 to $400), and obviously Ubuntu compatible. I saw a couple of videos on YouTube of Ubuntu touch monitors working beautifully, even on 11.04.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [list of Hardware supported by Multitouch .](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/HardwareSupport)